# How do i create Network security group in azure for python using subnet id and along with that which key i have to use for the subnet?

Tags: python, azure

How do i create **Network security group** in azure for python using **subnet id** and along with that which key i have to use for the subnet?

---

I am just creating a security group in azure using subnet i want to know which key is there for subnet to create security group in **python**?

Comment: What's the meaning of the `which key`?

Comment: in json object there will be some key name so i want to know that key name

Comment: how to assign security group in subnet

Comment: i had created a security group now i want to assign the security group to subnet